# How to go through the maximum amount of Tic Tac Toe possibilities?

Tags: c++

I wanted to know how many amounts of Tic Tac Toes possibilities there is, so I searched the web and found an mathematical theorem which says that there is **255168** possible games in Tic Tac Toe.

Website: http://www.se16.info/hgb/tictactoe.htm

So I wonder, I can make an program and see how fast can the computer go through each and every one of those possibilities, then I made this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

typedef int TTTField[9];

bool checkIfWon(TTTField j){
    if(j[0]==1&&j[1]==1&&j[2]==1) return true;
    if(j[0]==2&&j[1]==2&&j[2]==2) return true;
    if(j[3]==1&&j[4]==1&&j[5]==1) return true;
    if(j[3]==2&&j[4]==2&&j[5]==2) return true;
    if(j[6]==1&&j[7]==1&&j[8]==1) return true;
    if(j[6]==2&&j[7]==2&&j[8]==2) return true;
    if(j[0]==1&&j[3]==1&&j[6]==1) return true;
    if(j[0]==2&&j[3]==2&&j[6]==2) return true;
    if(j[1]==1&&j[4]==1&&j[7]==1) return true;
    if(j[1]==2&&j[4]==2&&j[7]==2) return true;
    if(j[2]==1&&j[5]==1&&j[8]==1) return true;
    if(j[2]==2&&j[5]==2&&j[8]==2) return true;
    if(j[0]==1&&j[4]==1&&j[8]==1) return true;
    if(j[0]==2&&j[4]==2&&j[8]==2) return true;
    if(j[2]==1&&j[4]==1&&j[6]==1) return true;
    if(j[2]==2&&j[4]==2&&j[6]==2) return true;
    return false;
}

bool checkIfItsOver(TTTField j){
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        if(j[i]==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool checkListOfFields(TTTField game, TTTField listOfFields[], int amountAdded){
    int i,j;
    for(j=0;j<amountAdded;j++){
        int temporaryField=0;
        for(i=0;i<9;i++){
            if(game[i]==listOfFields[j][i]) temporaryField++;
        }
        if(temporaryField==9)return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void clearField(TTTField game){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++) game[i]=0;
}

void addlistOfFields(TTTField game, TTTField listOfFields[], int amountAdded){
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) listOfFields[amountAdded][i]=game[i];
}

int main(){
    TTTField listOfFields[50000];
    TTTField temporaryField;
    int amountAdded=0,randA,round=1,roundCounter=0,amountPassed=0,amountOfWins=0,amountOfDraws=0,winWith5=0,winWith6=0,winWith7=0,winWith8=0,winWith9=0,roundAmountFinished=0;
    for(int i=0;roundCounter<100000;i++){
        clearField(temporaryField);
        roundAmountFinished=0;
        do{
            do{
                randA=rand()%9;
            }while(temporaryField[randA]!=0);
            temporaryField[randA]=round;
            if(checkIfWon(temporaryField)){
                break;
            }
            if(checkIfItsOver(temporaryField)){
                break;
            }
            round=round==1?2:1;
            roundAmountFinished++;
        }while(1);
        if(!checkListOfFields(temporaryField,listOfFields,amountAdded)){
            addlistOfFields(temporaryField,listOfFields,amountAdded);
            amountAdded++;
            if(checkIfWon(temporaryField)){
                amountOfWins++;
            }
            if(checkIfItsOver(temporaryField)){
                amountOfDraws++;
            }
            switch(roundAmountFinished){
                case 4:
                    winWith5++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    winWith6++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    winWith7++;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    winWith8++;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    winWith9++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(amountPassed==amountAdded){
            roundCounter++;
        }else roundCounter=0;
        amountPassed=amountAdded;
    }
    system("cls");
    printf("Total: %d, roundCounter: %d\nWins with 5 rounds:%d\nWins with 6 rounds:%d\nWins with 7 rounds:%d\nWins with 8 rounds:%d\nWins with 9 rounds:%d\namountOfWins: %d, amountOfDraws: %d",amountAdded,roundCounter,winWith5,winWith6,winWith7,winWith8,winWith9,amountOfWins,amountOfDraws);

    return 0;
}
```

But it returns me an total amount of: **1916**, which is different from the one in the website, and I wonder what is wrong with my code.

Some information about the code:

- The field is a array of integer with 9 indexes in which 1 represents crosses and 2 represents circles, also 0 is for null field.
- It generates an random value from 0~9 (if it hasn't been picked before) than it puts an 1 or 2 (depending whom round it is) always checking if someone won or the game has resulted in a draw.
- After finishing the game it will check if that possibility is already on the list, if it is it will do nothing and proceed to another one.
- It will finish when it went through 100k of possibilities without adding a single one to the list.

Where is the problem?

Comment: First move has 9 squares to pick from, next has 8, then 7, then 6, then 5.  That is the earliest that a win can happen.  And there are 9*8*7*6*5=15,120 ways that those first five moves can occur.  So we know the real answer must be (far) greater than that.  (Similarly there are 9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1=362,880 possible moves discounting early wins, so the real answer must be less than that.)

Comment: Well thanks for the comment, but as concerning math theorem of how many possibilities that can happen I've put an page showing how many there is, what I wanted is to go through every single one of them with my code

Comment: The best way to count the number of possible TicTacToe games is to do a recursive depth first search. Create a function that gets a game state, checks whether it's an end position (incrementing a counter and returning if so), then iterates through the possible moves at that state and calls itself with that state. Call once with an empty field and output the counter after the call returns.

Comment: You can reduce the comparisons by comparing cells to each other rather than a specific value.  For example, a win is (j[0] == j[1]) && (j[1] == j[2]).  Identifying the player that won, is the player that made the present move.

Answer (score 5):

I just noticed, `checkListOfFields` counts identical *boards* as identical *games*, wheras that is not *quite* true.  You're calculating the number of *end positions of boards* rather than games, which (although interesting) is a different thing altogether.

Consider these two games:

```
X| |   X|O|   X|O|X
-----  -----  -----
 | |    | |    | | 
-----  -----  -----
 | |    | |    | | 

 | |X   |O|X  X|O|X
-----  -----  -----
 | |    | |    | | 
-----  -----  -----
 | |    | |    | |
```

Your `checkListOfFields` function detects that these are the same game, and discards one.  It therefore *also discards one copy of all potential movesets that come after this*.

Comment: NICE note, didn't realized that, as for the code, I probably would have to change a lot to get this to work right?

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa: I haven't actually read all of your code, but I _suspect_ you could simply remove the `if(!checkListOfFields(temporaryField,listOfFields,amountAdded))` and _maybe_ it would work.

Comment: But by doing that I would be adding games that were already added, won't I? -- Edit -- Actually I can't do that since my loop ending is linked to that (which is if it passed 100k times without adding, it will finish, its actually silly, but I couldn't think of another way)

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa: waaaaaiiiit, I just read how `main` works.  You generate 100000 random games and store unique wins?  THat's not what I was expecting.  Yes.  You want to rewrite.

Comment: Haha, well thats what I was afraid of, any hints on the new version?

Comment: Generally the way to approach this is a recursive function that places moves.  The function receives a board, and for each open position, it tries to place a move there.  if it wins or loses, it record the result, otherwise, recurse to the other player.  Then undo that move and try the next possible move.  This effectively allows you to iterate all of the possible games, rather than randomly hoping to hit them.  It also takes almost no memory, since you don't need to store the boards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59674/discussion-between-guilherme-garcia-da-rosa-and-mooing-duck).

Answer (score 3):

I would probably write this problem recursively. Your method would take a board state, add a piece, check if it finishes (full or win), and if not, call the method again with the new board state. And every time you are full or win, increment some global counter. When the method returns, move your piece to a new spot.

Here's a rough idea of what i'd do:

```
recurseBoard(vector<vector<square> >& board, int pieceType) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          // If there's a piece there already, skip
          if (board[i][j] != 0) continue;
          // add the piece
          board[i][j] = pieceType;
          // if it's full or win, increment counter
          if (victory(board)) count++;
          else (recurseBoard(board), otherPieceType);
          // Clear the piece you just added
          board[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Good explanation, any hints on types? Should I use type such as Josh did?

Comment: Using the enum for type is a fairly good way to go about it. As for using the vectors, it helps with managing memory, but it's a bit up to personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would start by creating an `enum` for the square values instead of passing around and comparing numbers:

```
enum square {X, O, EMPTY};
```

So then you could keep the boards as 2d vectors:

```
vector<vector<square> > board (3, vector<square>(3, EMPTY));
```

Then finding the number of possible games could happen via recursion:

```
int find_games(vector<vector<square> >& board, square move) {
    if(game_over(board)) return 1;
    int num_moves = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < board.size(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < board[x].size(); y++) {
            if(board[x][y] != EMPTY) continue;
            board[x][y] = move; //test if player made a move here...
            num_moves += find_games(board, (move == X) ? Y : X);
            board[x][y] = EMPTY; //set space back to empty
        }
    }
    return number_moves;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! gonna take a look in it and later i'll provide a proper answer